# how to compare string in a column then copy data if string doesn't match

Tags: excel, vba

i want to insert data into excel workbook1 and copy it to workbook2. i need to make sure the new inserted data doesn't duplicate in both workbook . i use article number in column C (type string)
 to check whether the data is already in both workbook, if the data already exist, user need to reenter again.

i don't know how to use which string function to search the string. here's some of my code (this code is just for enter new data in workbook1 then copy to workbook2). the string that i use for checking is in column C(textbox1)

```
Workbooks("workbook1.xlsm").Activate
With Worksheets("sheet1")
    '~insert data
    .Range("B" & (i + CountProd)) = ComboBox1.Text
    .Range("C" & (i + CountProd)) = TextBox1.Text
    .Range("D" & (i + CountProd)) = TextBox2.Text
    .Range("E" & (i + CountProd)) = TextBox3.Text
    .Range("F" & (i + CountProd)) = TextBox4.Text
    .Range("G" & (i + CountProd)) = TextBox5.Text
    .Range("H" & (i + CountProd)) = ComboBox2.Text
    .Range("I" & (i + CountProd)) = TextBox6.Text
    .Range("J" & (i + CountProd)) = TextBox7.Text
    .Range("K" & (i + CountProd)) = TextBox8.Text

End With

Workbooks("workbook2.xlsm").Activate

RowNo = Workbooks(prod & " Input.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Cells(31, 3).Value
RowNo = RowNo + 32

Set sh1 = Workbooks("workbook2.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1")
Set sh2 = Workbooks("workbook1.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1")

sh1.Range(sh1.Cells(RowNo, 2), sh1.Cells(RowNo, 11)).Value = sh2.Range(sh2.Cells((i + CountProd), 2), sh2.Cells((i + CountProd), 11)).Value
'        End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you need is a function telling you whether a certain value exists in a range. Here's a generic piece of code you can use to check if [Arg] is contained anywhere in column [SCol] of range [SRng]

```
Function Exist(Arg As String, SRng As Range, SCol As Long) As Boolean
Dim Idx As Long

    Idx = 1
    Exist = False

    Do While SRng(Idx, SCol) <> ""
        If SRng(Idx, SCol) = Arg Then
            Exist = True
            Exit Do
        End If
        Idx = Idx + 1
    Loop

End Function
```

With this function you can check for existence of article number wherever you want ... example:

```
Sub Test()
' properly Dim your variables and objects
Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range

    ' set ranges first - you don't need to "activate" sheets unless you
    ' want the display to hop around
    ' avoid hardcoding as much as possible
    Set Rng1 = Workbooks("workbook1.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").[A1]
    Set Rng2 = Workbooks("workbook2.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").[A1]

    ' then start logic
    If Exist(TextBox1.Text, Rng1, 3) Then
        ' ANr exists somewhere in book1/sheet1/[C..C]
    Else
        ' ANr does not exist in book1/sheet1/[C..C]
    End If

    If Exist(TextBox1.Text, Rng2, 2) Then
        ' ANr exists somewhere in book2/sheet1/[B..B]
    Else
        ' ANr does not exist in book2/sheet1/[B..B]
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: thanks but the function return the initial value which is Exist=False although the textbox1.value exist in workbook2. the variable Idx is row number right?

Comment: check the column number (3rd parameter) in the call .... I set it 2 for the purpose of demonstration of the flexibility of this approach - and check the top left corner of both ranges (here [A1])

Comment: and yes ... Idx is the row number relative to the top left corner of the range you hand over

Answer (score 0):

To check whether the string in textbox1 is already present in column C you can use the "Find" function:

```
on error resume next
lRow = range("C:C").find(textbox1.text,...).row

if err.number = 0 then    'string found
   msgbox "Duplicate value. Try again."
   exit sub
end if

on error goto 0
```

Comment: thanks. i've tried lRow = Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C").Find("" & ArtNo, C32, 3).Row but it still no found the string although the string exist in workbook2

Comment: Have you researched what the arguments for the range.find method is?